# __autoload() vs include,will __autoload() output something?

Tags: php, include, autoload

I am developing a programm and it's based on third-party.I write a class and use __autoload() to load the class.
the program runs as following:
1.I upload my script to my remote server.
2.the third-party server will request my script with some get param.
3.my script return str and the third-party server will check the str,if the str is same to the get param,it's valid,if not,it's not valid.
now,the problem is:
**when I use the __autoload(),it will raise some error and when I replace __autoload with include/require it will run exactly.**
the code is as following:
    **wechat.class.php**

```
        public function __construct($options){
            $this->_token=isset($options['token'])?$options['token']:'';
        }

        public function test(){
            var_dump($this->_token);
        }

        private function checkSignature(){
            $signature = isset($_GET["signature"])?$_GET["signature"]:'';
            $timestamp = isset($_GET["timestamp"])?$_GET["timestamp"]:'';
            $nonce = isset($_GET["nonce"])?$_GET["nonce"]:'';

            $token = $this->_token;
            $tmpArr = array($token, $timestamp, $nonce);
            sort($tmpArr, SORT_STRING);
            $tmpStr = implode( $tmpArr );
            $tmpStr = sha1( $tmpStr );

            if( $tmpStr == $signature ){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function valid($return=false){
            $echostr=isset($_GET['echostr'])?$_GET['echostr']:'';
            if($return){
                if($echostr){
                    if($this->checkSignature()){
                        return $echostr;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }else{
                    return $this->checkSignature();
                }
            }else{
                if($echostr){
                    if($this->checkSignature()){
                        die($echostr);
                    }else{
                        die('no access');
                    }
                }else{
                    if($this->checkSignature()){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        die('no access');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

**wechat.php**

```
<?php
    function __autoload($classname){
        include "./wechat/".$classname.".class.php";
    }
    $options=array(
            'token'=>'tudouya',
        );
    $wechat=new Wechat($options);
    $wechat->valid();
?>
```

addition,my php version is 5.4.I test this script for long and find both __autoload() and include will work normally in php 5.2,but not in php 5.4.
I even think if there are bugs in php,but I can't decide.
hope I describe my question clearly and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Better use absolute paths with the `__DIR__` directive.

Comment: Your script should run fine...(I guess that the path is correct...) By the way, I recommend you to use the `spl_autoload_register` instead of `__autoload` [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) .

Comment: @KeVin,@Debflav,I try what you say,it still can't work.I think this is not the question point.

Comment: Maybe it won't solve your problem. But if you migrate to PHP5.4 you should note that:
_"spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
include "./wechat/".strtolower($classname).".class.php";
```

It will try to include Wechat.class.php otherwise (with the uppercase w, which does not exist as a file.

Comment: thanks,I try what you say again and it work.but another question raise.as you say, (with the uppercase w, which does not exist as a file),if this,why I can new an object and  the programm doesn't raise an error?

Comment: Maybe your `error_reporting` is not set to `E_ALL` because trying to instantiate an unknown class should raise a Fatal error.

Comment: @Debflav,first my error_reporting is set to **E_ALL**.also,I can instantiate the class and call the member function.even,the member function can run correctly!

Comment: @tudouya So, sorry, I misunderstood your real problem.

Comment: The classname is Wechat (uppercase W), but the FILEname is class.wechat.php (lowercase w). So include('class.wechat.php'); (with lowercase w) works while you have to use new Wechat(); (uppercase W) to make an instance of the class.